# How to measure the EMF in the air and log it into a csv file?

Tags: gps, android

I would like to build a device measures the [EMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field) in air,it should be sensitive for a wide band (broadband) EMF, And I want it to be able to log into a csv file the time and amplitude of EMF (intensity). 
I would like to connect a gps device to it so I'll be able to calculate the velocity of my car while measuring EMF.

By the end of the day I want to measure how much power I can gain by driving around high voltage cables.

1. Can you recommend me an [EMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field) I can use and an Android based board I
   will be able to connect the EMF to and take logs?
2. Is it possible to make a draw of the field around me something like that:[image]
3. Is it right to say the energy I can gain in the best case is:
   $$Energy = Force*distance = q(V\times B) \cdot distance$$

Answer (score 2):

You can meausure the electric field with something called a *field mill*.  That is two electrodes that change orientation by mechanical rotation.  Any static field will cause a relative change in voltage between the electrodes as they rotate thru a cycle.  This device measures the field in a plane, so you need multiple to measure the 3D field vector at a location.

The rest of what you say makes little sense, particularly the part about gaining energy by driving around near high voltage cables.

Comment: How can I use the EMF to charge a battery for example?

Comment: @0x90 - You can't. There isn't enough power there to do anything meaningful.

Comment: @ConnorWolf REALLY ? http://www.gizmag.com/electromagnetic-harvester/26130/

Comment: @ConnorWolf it isn't free energy, I want to test it, in the worst case i'll have fun

Comment: @0x90 - The energy you'll get is going to be in the order of nanowatts or picowatts.